# Adding a tab to a product page in magento

Tags: magento

I have a magento website and I want to add a tab to the product page to add the ingredients of a product. From the magento admin I have created a new attribute called "Ingredients" and added it to the attributes set for that product.

Here is how the tabs looks like now:

[image]

But my problem is to show this attribute on the front-end. I have found the section in the catalog.xml file where the tabs are defined but I am not able to add the ingredients attribute to the page as a tab.

```
    <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Product Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
                <!--<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>upsell_products</alias><title>We Also Recommend</title><block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block><template>catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml</template></action>-->
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>

                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="tag"><alias>product.tags</alias><title>Product Tags</title><block>tag/product_list</block><template>tag/list.phtml</template></action>

                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>delivery</alias><title>Delivery Info</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/delivery_returns.phtml</template></action>
            </block>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Under `info_tabs` taking reference from description, you can add another tab. Also, your xml layout isn't of `rwd theme`. so i am not sure but this should work.

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description1</alias><title>Tab title</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/ingredient.phtml</template></action>
```

Now on file `ingredients.phtml` at `catalog/product/view/ingredient.phtml` get the attribute value printed.

```
<?php 
      $_product = Mage::registry('current_product'); //current product object
      echo $_product->getData('ingredient'); //attribute code ingredient ?>
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thank you I tried to show the tab, after several tries and modifications the only way the tab showed was when I had this in the phtml file. `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('ingredients')->toHtml(); ?>
<!-- <?php $_product = Mage::registry('current_product'); //current product object echo $_product->getData('ingredient'); //attribute code ingredient ?>
-->`

Comment: What is weird that when I remove the commented part, the tab does not show.

Comment: @Rami So, `ingredients` is your block id ? you were calling it attribute. The tab doesn't appear when printing value on phtml file is null; i.e if phtml file has nothing, the tab doesn't appear. you can also test with some static text/element instead..

Comment: @Rami , you can upvote/accept the answer, if not provide me feedback.